# comparing the output of Automl

Tags: azure, h2o, automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

im getting different output for feature importance, when I run the automl in azure, google and h2o. even though the data is same and all the features are also same. what would be the reason for it.
is there any other method to compare the models

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior, H2OAutoML is not reproducible by default.
To make H2OAutoML reproducible you need to set `max_models`, `seed` and exclude DeepLearning (`exclude_algos=["DeepLearning"]`) and make sure `max_runtime_secs` is not set.

To compare models you can use [model explanations](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/explain.html) or you can just compare the [model metrics](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html).